# PHP Ajax Image Upload within form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm working on creating a real estate website where it would allow agents to add their property.  For adding the property I created a form.  For uploading the picture within the same form, I'm using a jquery plugin which uploads the picture before the form is submitted.  I have created a hidden field in the form and with php I am filling that field with a unique id to identify the picture belonging to the property.

What if the user did not submit the main form (keep in mind user can close browser, tab, or even navigate away from page) and I already uploaded the pictures.  How can I detect these pictures?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you just submitting the image with the rest of the form?

Comment: why half of the world want asynchronous image upload...:D WHY? :D

Comment: well im actually want to archive this,user can upload the picture within the form,give them name, and arrange them by dragging for slide show in the main display..... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxERIN6xffi6ZkpxbURsSXdPZ28/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onbeforeunload` event to detect if the user is leaving the page and then make an ajax call to delete the images.

Comment: but when form is submitted and i want to negavite to differnt page to show them listing does it also call the onbeforeunload?.

Comment: on submit you can set variable to true and in onbeforeunload check variable status